# preg_match('/[a-z0-9\-]+/i', $u) $ Sign

Tags: php, preg-match

When I submit this form I keep getting a match which it shouldn't do. I know it has something to do with the dollar sign but I can't work out the combination and I can't seem to find the right answer on Google.

```
<?php
if ( isset( $_POST['test'] ) ) {
    $u = $_POST['test'];
    echo preg_match('/[a-z0-9\-]+/i', $u);
}
?>

<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="test" value="12$abc213">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You forgot to mention what it should and shouldn't match and what the input string is.

Comment: Can you see the $ sign in the form field value?  The preg_match doesn't match a dollar sign so it shouldn't pass.  Sorry, thought that was pretty obvious.

Comment: That should be two matches `12` and `abc213`. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must match the beginning and end of the string, or it will pass with matching substrings:

```
preg_match('/^[a-z0-9\-]+$/i', $u);
```

Comment: +1 because you actually gave an explanation instead of just posting a line of code. =o)

Answer (score 3):

Should be

```
preg_match('/^[a-z0-9\-]+$/i', $u)
```

Comment: Love the competition. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

Your preg_match is finding matches because '1' is a match, '2' is amatch, 'abc213' is a match, 'a' is a match, etc. Do you want to be sure the whole entire string matches? then try this pattern:

```
preg_match("/^[a-z0-9\-]+$/i", $u);
```

Wrapping the expression in ^..$ will mean it must start and end with that sequence. This will not match unless all of the characters in the string match this pattern, where yours would match if any of the "sequence of characters" in the string match the pattern.

Comment: Actually if you would do `preg_match_all` you will find out there are actually only 2 matches.

Comment: @PeeHaa, that's because of greedy vs ungreedy. In reality, PHP will be greedy, so it would match a sequence until a char is found that doesn't follow that sequence. so instead of immediately matching '1' and then matching '2' and then matching '12', a greedy REGEX'er would match only '12'. And for the most part, greedy is more useful than non-greedy when it comes to regex. I hope my explanation of '1' being a match to that pattern doesn't confuse anyone... :S